# redirecting one to another Controller using spring mvc 3

Tags: java, spring-mvc

below is my controller

```
  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String ABC(Registratio registration, ModelMap modelMap,
        HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response){
        if(somecondition=="false"){
           return "notok";  // here iam returning only the string 
          }
          else{
               // here i want to redirect to another controller shown below
           }
}

 @RequestMapping(value="/checkPage",method = RequestMethod.GET,)
public String XYZ(ModelMap modelMap,
        HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response){
       return "check";   // this will return check.jsp page
}
```

since the Controller **ABC** is @ResponceBody type  it will always return as string, but i want that in else contion it should be redirected to the **XYZ** controller and from which it return a **jsp** page which i can show.
 i tried using **return "forward:checkPage";** also with  **return "redirect:checkPage";**
but doesn't work.
any help.

Thanks.

Comment: have you checked out this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6424409/787375) maybe it's useful to you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you have to remove @ResponseBody if you want to either render response yourself or redirect in one controller method based on some condition, try this:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
//remove @ResponseBody
public String ABC(Registratio registration, ModelMap modelMap,
    HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response){
    if(somecondition=="false"){
        // here i am returning only the string 
        // in this case, render response yourself and just return null 
        response.getWriter().write("notok");
        return null;
    }else{
        // redirect
        return "redirect:checkPage";
    }
}
```

--edit--

if you want to access controller via ajax, you'd better include the datatype parameter on you request to indicate that you are simply expecting a text response:

```
$.get("/AAA-Web/abc",jQuery.param({})
    ,function(data){ 
        alert(data); 
    }, "text");
```

Comment: but when it goes to if condition "response.getWriter().write("notok");" what is this for. ?

Comment: "response.getWriter().write("notok");" means render response yourself, which has the same effect with @ResponseBody on method

Comment: but i am calling from jquery as $.get("/AAA-Web/abc",jQuery.param({}),function(data){ alert(data);  }); but in data response from ABC controller its show me   "[object XMLDocument]" When it goes to if Condition .. rest of your suggestion working fine.

Comment: the data parameter in the callback function will get value "notok" if somecondition=="false"

Comment: try to call data.toString()?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34968/discussion-between-asur-and-septem)

Answer (score 1):

```
return new ModelAndView("redirect:/admin/index");
```

The code above works for me. I was redirecting from the present controller to index in AdminController.

Answer (score -1):

edirected to the XYZ controller and from which it return a jsp page instead of using the following code i/e

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/checkPage",method = RequestMethod.GET,)
    public String XYZ(ModelMap modelMap,
    HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response){
   return "check";   // this will return check.jsp page
   }
```

use

```
  @RequestMapping(value ="/checkPage",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView  XYZ(HttpServletRequest req)
{

    ModelAndView m=new ModelAndView();

    m.setViewName("check");
    return m;
}
```

Comment: Try this for your answer it will definitely

Comment: ya @Mohsin Shaikh but ABC controller is not redirecting to XYZ controller.. if it then only i can check.